# Some magic in find

Tags: regex, meteor

In Mongo FIND( regexp ), the number of found records is different from Meteor.

mongodb side:

```
> db.products.find({name:/clp/ig}).count()
4
```

crome js console:

```
> products.find({name:/clp/ig}).count()
2
```

Data are very simple:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("514d39f087696bb4cc3b549d"), "code" : "P615", "name" : "PENNASOL         WERKZEUGMASCHINENGETRIEBEOEL CLP 68" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("514d39f087696bb4cc3b549e"), "code" : "P616", "name" : "PENNASOL         WERKZEUGMASCHINENGETRIEBEOEL CLP 100" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("514d39f087696bb4cc3b549f"), "code" : "P617", "name" : "PENNASOL         WERKZEUGMASCHINENGETRIEBEOEL CLP 150" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("514d39f087696bb4cc3b54a0"), "code" : "P618", "name" : "PENNASOL         WERKZEUGMASCHINENGETRIEBEOEL CLP 220" }
```

Collection

```
var products = new Meteor.Collection('products');

Meteor.publish( 'products', function(){
  products.find();
});
```

Could be a bug? And where?

ps: checked on different computers. same magic.

Answer (score 0):

The data may not yet be on the client when you make the call. Do you use it anywhere? The data is only fetched when it's used, so when you do the `find` on the client, you get result with what's already there, and the other items just start their way through the net.

To test if this is the case:

- Do the same find on the server (in `Meteor.startup` for example) and log the results.
- On the client, do `Products.find({}).fetch();`. Wait some time, then do your query.

Answer (score 0):

All data is too old(may be year).

```
products.find({name:/clp/ig}).fetch();
```

answer is:

```
P615   PENNASOL WERKZEUGMASCHINENGETRIEBEOEL CLP 68
P617   PENNASOL WERKZEUGMASCHINENGETRIEBEOEL CLP 150
```

other

```
products.find({name:/clp 220/ig}).fetch();
```

answer is

```
P618   PENNASOL WERKZEUGMASCHINENGETRIEBEOEL CLP 220
```

It's real magic.